# SQL query fails, 42000 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

This query:

```
INSERT INTO languages(id_639_3,part2B,part2T,part1,scope,language_type,ref_name,comment) VALUES ('aaa','','','','I','L','Ghotuo','');
```

Fails with the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO languages(id_639_3,part2B,part2T,part1,scope,language_type,ref_na' at line 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO languages(id_639_3,part2B,part2T,part1,scope,language_type,ref_name,comment) VALUES ('aaa','','','','I','L','Ghotuo',''))
```

Comment: put some backticks around those field names and see what happens.  I would also suggest you format your code so that mysql can give you a better indication of where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO languages (id_639_3,part2B,part2T,part1,scope,language_type,ref_name,comment)
VALUES ('aaa','','','','I','L','Ghotuo','');
```

Why don't you try without the `'' / null` values? Like this:

```
INSERT INTO languages (id_639_3,scope,language_type,ref_name)
VALUES ('aaa','I','L','Ghotuo');
```

To get a better error message break it up into several lines. -- You're also going to want to put a space between your table_name and the parenthesis-enclosed column_names.

Comment: Seems it's the null values that are causing the issue. Thanks.